# apple Watch: remove status bar for Interface Controller

Tags: apple-watch

Is it possible to remove status bar for a particular Interface Controller or customise Interface controller title text in any way ?

Comment: Did you find anything yet? I'm trying to figure this out too

Comment: @Hless: I read in some apple developer forum  that it is not possible. Perhaps because it shows time.

Comment: It kind of makes sense in a way. Thanks for the response. Plan B it is ;D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Apple Watch Programming Guide you can customize interface controller title text color by setting your App’s Key Color.

> Every WatchKit app has an associated key color, which is applied to the >following UI elements:
>
> -The title string in the status bar
>
> -The app name in short look notifications
>
> An app’s key color is stored in the Global Tint property of the app’s storyboard. To access this property, select your storyboard and display the File inspector. Select one of several preexisting colors from the popup menu or use the color picker to specify a custom color.

This is all we have as of today.

---

About if it is possible to hide the status bar...
The closer result you will get is by using modal interfaces.
In this ones, the clock will be invisible but the status bar will remain there holding the interface title.

Comment: I set the tint colour (as stated) to red and all I get the same old black (in the watch App). Should I see the change reflected in the storyboard?