# Apple Watch: Hide Status Bar from interface controller

Tags: apple-watch

For my app it makes no sense to have the current time on the right corner of the screen and the black status bar as well.

Is there any way to corner this?

Comment: Did you find anything yet? I'm trying to figure this out too

Comment: Nope, I didn't find anything. I would really want to

Comment: Same question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938171/apple-watch-remove-status-bar-for-interface-controller?noredirect=1#comment44468627_27938171 

Apparently it's not possible. Perhaps at a later time when the thing is actually released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an API for controlling the visibility of the status bar in WatchKit.