# Is it possible to hide the time in the Apple Watch header?

Tags: xcode, time, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I want to create an app that displays the time. This makes the time in the header redundant.

Comment: I think this is a duplicated post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938171/apple-watch-remove-status-bar-for-interface-controller?noredirect=1#comment44468627_27938171 Apparently, you can't

Answer (score 1):

You may present a view controller modally. In this case, no time is displayed at the top. However, you should be aware of the following [App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> Watch Apps whose primary function is telling time will be rejected