# How to use/get Apple Watch Full Screen mode

Tags: fullscreen, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

**I don't want to hide time, but want to use full screen**

In the storyboard on the interface controller settings I set the checkbox "Full Screen" and "Fixed to screen edges" to ON.

In the storyboard I can see the full screen mode is working and the WKInterfaceGroup is scaled to the entire display.

But unfortunately on the watch device/simulator it does not work.

The group has alignment center/center OR center/top and width and height are set to "Relative to Container"

How can I really use the full screen mode?.

[image]

I just have to add a label equal to Time in top black space. I want to show some text here. I have seen this in some other apps, They are using this space. Even in Apple design guide lines docs, they use this space. I am adding these reference screenshots also.

[image]
[image]

In above pictures, you can see they used this top space for titles. I also want to add a label to show some text equal to time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide or remove the time from the Apple Watch status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067952/how-to-hide-or-remove-the-time-from-the-apple-watch-status-bar)

Answer (score 2):

This is a really weird bug. After digging around I've found a way to fill the whole screen. It's not pretty but I'm consistently getting full screen if i'm adding a sprite kit scene into a "main group". Again; it's not an elegant fix but it works and isn't really that resource intensive. Hope this works for you too!

Comment: hi @crankblaster can you add new group in sprite kit scene ?

Comment: Hi I dont belive so, but you can just put other groups in the main group along with the spritekit scene, that shouldn't effect the full screen. All the best

Comment: Just FYI, I've seen a couple other folks note that Apple may reject apps that do this sort of thing. I'm guessing it could make it through though since it doesn't occlude the clock.